# CakePHP returning multiple records from a habtm

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a habtm relation between questions and categories. This habtm relation is standard and setup in the respective models. I now have the following issue. In a controller action I have an array of several question ids. I want to return all of the categories that are linked to these questions. The find I am using looks as followed.

```
$case_questions_categories = $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('OR' => $case_question_id_array)));

    // Here the $case_question_id_array is generated as followed:
    foreach($question['CaseQuestion'] as $case_question) {
        $case_question_id_array[] = "Category.question_id = " . $case_question['id'];
    }
```

Its clear that this will not work, and it throws the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Category.question_id' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name`, `Category`.`slug`, `Category`.`category_order`, `Category`.`created`, `Category`.`modified`, `Category`.`is_deleted` FROM `streetofwalls`.`categories` AS `Category` WHERE `Category`.`question_id` = 182
```

This makes sense because the join table from the habtm relation is not referenced in the query I have generated. How do I get habtm relation to be properly handled so that I can pass a group of question ids and be returned the relevant categories.

Thank you to anyone who offers time or help.

Comment: You could unbind the habtm and bind a belongsTo on the fly: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly

Comment: @timstermatic I'm not sure what you mean. Is binding a cakePHP thing?

Comment: Yes, in the controller you can add a different type of association on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a join

The kind of sql query you need to generate is:

```
SELECT 
    categories.* from categories 
JOIN 
    categories_questions ON (categories_questions.category_id = categories.id) 
WHERE 
    categories_questions.question_id IN (list, of, question, ids)
```

The simplest way to do that is to just use the `join` key in your query - this is also [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

Applied to the example in the question that'd be:

```
$ids = array()
foreach($question['CaseQuestion'] as $q) {
    $ids[] = $q['id'];
}

$this->Category->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'CategoriesQuestion.id' => $ids // You do not need an OR
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'categories_questions',
            'alias' => 'CategoriesQuestion',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Category.id = CategoriesQuestion.category_id'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains why I could not find that info, I was looking in the documentation for the find method. This is what I needed.